# Connect to https Site(Server)

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have some java-app, and i want to establish a connection to some https Site, how can i do this, using URLConnection? Should i use trust store, when certificate from this site was signed using a valid certificate authority?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. URLConnection should work. For example,

```
        URL a = new URL("https://login.yahoo.com");
        conn = a.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

JRE comes with a default trust store with most of the CA certs. As long as the cert is signed by one of them, you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: But it doesn't works, i recieve such Exception:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: This excpetion i recieve when i have tried to call method connect() from the URLConnection

Comment: The server is not configured properly. Looks like the port is not configured for SSL. Try the URL in browser to see what happens?

Comment: Very strange, but now is ok, i didn't correct anything:) Thank u!

Comment: And one more question, is this connection secure?:)

Comment: Of course it's secure, that's what the S stands for in https.