# How to bypass certificate checking in Java

Tags: java, ssl

In my code, I am calling:
 HttpResponse resp = usingClient.execute(urlGet, hc_context) ;
which is responsible to do certificate check.
My requirement is I don't want this certificate checking.
Can someone please tell me how to bypass this certificate checking.

The api where I am using it is:
public static Repository getRepositoryInformation(HttpClient usingClient,

```
HttpClientContext hc_context, String serverLocation, String loginId, String password, boolean anonymous) throws RAMServiceException{
        Repository repository = null;
        HttpGet urlGet = createGet(serverLocation+REPOSITORY_INFO);
        try {
            HttpResponse resp = usingClient.execute(urlGet, hc_context) ;
            if(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                throw new RAMServiceException(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), resp.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42229760

Comment: Hope this[1] fulfills your requirement. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https